# Client IP address at server using RDMA?

Tags: linux, ip-address, rdma

I have an RDMA program which works well. Now I have a requirement that I want to get the client IP address after the RDMA connection is established.

Socket API `recv` automatically provided source address information. How about RDMA? Seems it's base on QP (Queue Pair) which doesn't provide the client-side address info, and it's event-based, I have `RDMA_CM_EVENT_CONNECT_REQUEST` and `RDMA_CM_EVENT_ESTABLISHED`.

Maybe only way to do it is to pass the address info in the RDMA message or in `context` for `rdma_cm_id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use rdma_get_peer_addr: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/rdma_get_peer_addr.3.html